# iOS Autolayout Constraints: I am trying to get my image to be evenly distance from the edge of the UIView

Tags: ios, constraints, ios-autolayout

I am running into an issue regarding auto layout with constraints. I am trying to keep my image evenly distant from the edges of my UIView. This isn't working for me and need some help regarding it.

Here are the images I took from my simulator. You can see the iPhone image(bottom image) has more spacing between the image and the edge of the view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what constraints do you have set currently?

Comment: Pin the images leading space, trailing space, top space to superview then set the height as a constant

Comment: I've added the left pin, right pin constraint and y position constraint.

Comment: and have you added the height constraint?

Comment: sorry, no I haven't let me try that out.

Comment: It works, thanks. I'll would like to accept it as  an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the constraints of UIImageView as Top space to UIView,LeadingSpace to UIView,TrailingSpace to UIView, And set the UIImageView Hight constraint as much you want .And also put the UIImage content mode is aspect to Fill or Fit .Remember to put the Top,Left,Right Constraint value as a standard (e.g:8 points).